# Uniformly continuous on each of $A$ and $B$, not on $A\cup B$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have a homework problem that asks me to find a function defined on subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R$ such that the function is uniformly continuous on each of $A$ and $B$, and is continuous but not uniformly continuous on $A \cup B$.

I have the example of the "jump-discontinuity" (where function is discontinuous at a point, period).

I also tried using that functions mapped from cpt sets to reals will be uniformly continuous...but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'd appreciate a hint, or anything! Thank you!

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$, subsets of some metric space, or specifically subsets of $\mathbb R$?  Do you want $f$ to be continuous?  Why can you not answer this with a jump-discontinuity in $\mathbb R$?  What did you try to do with that example?

Comment: I'd say subsets of R, since we haven't really worked with anything else.

Comment: I'm just curious, I guess. Is there a continuous function, *f*, and sets *A* and *B* s.t. *f* is uniformly continuous on each of the sets but not the union? Otherwise, I'll just use the jump discontinuity example.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A=[0,1)$, $B=(1,2]$, and let $f$ be constant on each of $A$ and $B$, with different values.

Comment: I suppose the jump discontinuity is the way to go, then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @hal: Sure, but here $f$ has no discontinuity on its domain, $A\cup B = [0,2]\setminus \{1\}$.  It is the case that it cannot be continuously extended to $[0,2]$, because extending the domain to the whole interval would create a jump discontinuity. (A uniformly continuous function on a subset of $\mathbb R$ always would have a continuous extension to the closure of its domain.)

Comment: I see, I'd completely forgotten that the domain didn't include {1}. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @hal: Yeah.   There are no examples where $A$ and $B$ are compact if you want the function continuous as you said in a comment, so for bounded examples at least one has to be nonclosed; here they're both missing the limit point $1$.  There are also examples with both $A$ and $B$ closed, but unbounded.